# Combinatorial Proof for Choosing $k$ Objects from $n$ Objects

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

Is there a purely combinatorial proof of the fact that $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of ways to choose $k$ objects from $n$ objects that avoids using any known facts about $\binom{n}{k}$ (i.e. the pascal's triangle relations)?

My first idea would be to just do it by induction, but the inductive step would use the pascal's triangle relationship.

Any solution or reference would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: My definition of $\binom{n}{k}$ is $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.

Comment: If we're going to prove something about $\binom nk$ we need to know what definition of $\binom nk$ you're using. Is it **(1)** the number of $k$-element subsets of an $n$-element set, or **(2)** the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^n,$  or **(3)** defined recursively by the Pascal identity, or **(4)** defined as $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!},$ or **(5)** some other way?

Comment: What is your definition of $\binom{n}{k}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrangements of $k$ objects out of $n$, without repetitions, i.e. $\Delta^n_k=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ provide us the number of different $k$-tuples chosen out of $n$ objects. Since $k$ distinct elements form a single subset but  $k!$ different $k$-tuples i.e. they have $k!$ different orders, you have to divide $\Delta^n_k$ with $k!$ to get the $k$-element subsets (which are by definition unorderd):
$$
\binom{n}{k}=\frac{\Delta^n_k}{k!}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
$$